# Ubuntu 20.04 root and home paritions problem / low disk on root filesystem

Tags: partitioning, root, home-directory

Ookay, so this morning I got message I've only 300 mb free space on root filesystem.So I cleaned everything I could. Now there are 5.2GB available.

But, (i'm novice user) I see that I might have made a mistake when installing Ubuntu.
Then i made 40GB space for "/" and 200GB for '/home'. Seems that the 200GB are not used, and the files in '/home' are using root's space. And stuff like vscode and gimpp are using root's space. I've attach photo of 'df -T' output. How do I fix this..? [terminal:$ df -T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKXDA.jpg)

Comment: It happens to a lot of folks. Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions).

Comment: It's helpful; I started gparted, but it doesn't let me to resize the partition. I will try with 'Ubuntu installation' to see what happens...

Comment: If the application does not let you resize the partition, then *there is a reason!*. You must carefully read both the instructions and your output to learn the reason and thereby avoid breaking your system and losing your data. Re-partitioning is inherently risky -- patience and preparation are the keys to success.

Comment: Okay, thanks....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Right, so basically from 'Ubuntu live installation' i deleted the swap partition, deleted the unused '/home'. Then, it didn't let me resize, so I restarted and went into installed Ubuntu and from gparted extended '/' directory and made swap.It works.